# Django, не понимаю как связать три таблицы моделей

Tags: python, django, django-orm

У меня есть три таблицы

Первая таблица:

```
    class Person(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        last_position = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Вторая таблица:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    university = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    admission_date = models.DateField()
    graduation_date = models.DateField()
```

Третья таблица:

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hiring_date = models.DateField()
    fired_date = models.DateField()
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

У каждого Person может быть несколько Education и Experience. Как мне правильно организовать взаимоотношения таблиц? Я в тупике, пробовал через foreign_key, но выдавало ошибку об отсутствии поля person_id, хотя оно должно создаваться автоматически. Наведите меня на верный путь, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_position = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        
        
class Education(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # тут связь на внешную таблицу
    university = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    admission_date = models.DateField()
    graduation_date = models.DateField()
    
class Experience(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # тут связь на внешную таблицу
    company = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hiring_date = models.DateField()
    fired_date = models.DateField()
    job_location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Таким образом можно связать ваши три таблицы. Что касается on_delete - в вашем случае наверное уместнее использовать [CASCADE](https://docs-djangoproject-com.translate.goog/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru#django.db.models.CASCADE). Механика 'CASCADE' проста - удаляя Person удаляются связные Education и Experience

Ваша ошибка 'об отсутсвии поля person_id' связанна с тем что вы пытаетесь обратиться к объекту модели Person 'person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)' (и она должно уже существовать в бд). Если же вам нужно связать [ForeignKey](https://docs-djangoproject-com.translate.goog/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru#foreignkey) таблицы с нуля, надо обращаться к имени модели 'Person' что бы создать связи. Это если совсем коротко :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сегодня проверил, все равно ругался на person_id, сам создал это поле и поставил его как primary_key и все заработало корректно